# Массив из значений false

Tags: java

Читаю книгу и вычитал, что по умолчанию переменные типа `boolean` имеют значение `false`. Следовательно, если я создам массив из четырёх значений `false`, мне достаточно просто написать так?

```
boolean[] flags = new boolean[4];
```

А если так?

```
Boolean[] flags = new Boolean[4];
```

Или в массивax это правило не работает? Будет `null`? Если работает, то где не работает?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Boolean` - объект, и для него будет `null`. `boolean` - примитив, и для него будет `false`

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сам дочитал и понял :)